# WebStorm "eslint --fix on save" feature doesn't work. But in terminal ESLint works well

Tags: typescript, eslint, webstorm

I am using "eslint --fix on save" functionality. Yesterday it stopped working. But it still works well in terminal. This problem appears only in WebStorm.

IDE returns error:

```
Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.json » ./node_modules/gts/#overrides[0]': No valid exports main found for '/Users/yurygrinko/WebstormProjects/lynx-project-app/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils/node_modules/eslint-utils'
Referenced from: /Users/yurygrinko/WebstormProjects/lynx-project-app/node_modules/gts/build/src/index.js

Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.json » ./node_modules/gts/#overrides[0]': No valid exports main found for '/Users/yurygrinko/WebstormProjects/lynx-project-app/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils/node_modules/eslint-utils'
Referenced from: /Users/yurygrinko/WebstormProjects/lynx-project-app/node_modules/gts/build/src/index.js
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:492:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:847:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yurygrinko/WebstormProjects/lynx-project-app/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils/dist/ast-utils/eslint-utils/astUtilities.js:23:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
Process finished with exit code -1
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "plugin:react-hooks/recommended"],
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "error",
        "node/no-unpublished-import": "off",
        "no-shadow": "off",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
        "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
        "react/prop-types": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom"],
    "outDir": "build",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "gts lint",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "posttest": "yarn run lint",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.6",
    "md5": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.20.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.20.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.17.13",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.170",
    "@types/md5": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.5",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/sendgrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils": "^4.26.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "fauna-gql-upload": "^2.3.0",
    "faunadb": "^4.1.3",
    "gts": "^3.1.0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

[image: WebStorm ESLint configuration]
**.idea/../eslint.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="EslintConfiguration">
    <files-pattern value="{**/*,*}.{ts,tsx}" />
    <option name="fix-on-save" value="true" />
  </component>
</project>
```

I tried to update WebStorm ESLint configuration manually but it changed nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an open [issues list](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/idea). Maybe you can find an existing issue for your problem. If not, you could open one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ESLint settings to **Manual configuration** and specify the ESlint working directory explicitly as described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_manual_configuration

Comment: it doesn't help. ESLint still works well in terminal